# Default parameters for command in bash

Tags: bash, mysql, .bash-profile

Setting up a new development VM, and I'm hoping to make it so that the default MySQL user is always a specific user unless otherwise specified.

Ideal command:

```
$ mysql # translates to mysql -uMyUser -pMyPass
$ mysql -uMyOtherUser -pMyOtherPass # login behaves as expected
```

I only need this to apply to one specific user, so this could be in `.bash_profile`. If it can be applied to all users, even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alias mysql="mysql -uMyOtherUser -pMyOtherPass"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can assign the default user and/or password in MySQL configuration file, that's `my.cnf` for user profile or system-wide. [More](https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/04/01/how-to-find-mysql-configuration-file/).